# how to make fda drug search website

Tags: json, ajax

can someone please tell me what im doing wrong?  im trying to make fda search website that finds what a drug is for. it uses fdas api. but nothing is happening when i click on the find button. i used json and ajax call but its still not working. ANy help is very much appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<head>
    <title>FDA API</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One|Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>

    <nav>
        <img src="img/fda.gif">
    </nav>

    <div id='wrapper'>
        <h1 id='title'>FDA DRUG SEARCH</h1>
            <input id="fdaSearch" type="text" placeholder="Type Name of drug" /><br><br>
            <button onclick="search()">Search</button>
        <div id='effects'></div>
    </div>
<script >

function search(){
    $("#effects").html('');
    var key = "T4No04ciH8D7nIsp6OflpZT1i2JC6XLxd8HUnhIc"
    var searchTerm = document.getElementById("fdaSearch").value

    $.ajax({

        url: "https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?api_key="+ key + "&search=" + searchTerm+"&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            for(i=0;i<15;i++){
                var results = (data.results[i].term)
          if(data.results[i].term === "DRUG INEFFECTIVE"){
            results[i].term = ""
          }else if(data.results[i].term === ""){
            document.write("Try another search") 
          }else{
                    $("#effects").append(results + " " + "<br>")
                console.log(data.results[i].term)
          }

            }
        },
       type: 'GET'
    });
}




</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using jQuery to do this but you are running your script before the jQuery library is downloaded. Also, you are using an old version of jQuery.

You need to move your download script into the `<head>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or whatever version jQuery is at right now. `src` should be a link to the actual source you are using to get jQuery. The one I show is Google's and should work for you.